# debug two applications in tomcat in different eclipse instances

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have two server java applications.

One of the applications is running in one `eclipse` instance - it connected to remote tomcat application to port `5005`.

Another application is running in another `eclipse` instances. But when I try to connect it to remote application to port `5005` - I've got `connection refused` error.

I start tomcat after setting `JAVA_OPTS`

```
C:\Users\username>set JAVA_OPTS=-Dapp.environment=LOCAL -Dapp.config.dir=/D:\config -Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX
:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=5005,server=y,suspend=n
```

and then use `catalina start`.

So the question is:

*How to allow debugging of two applications in different `eclipse` instances but connected to the same Tomcat instance?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a separate copy of the Tomcat directory for the other Eclipse. Proceed with the normal process of creating new server with `New -> Server`. Be sure to select the duplicate Tomcat as the server. Then after that, double click the server in the Servers tab and change the `Server Ports` to be different with the first Tomcat instance.

Comment: Well you can also use a single Eclipse instance and just make sure the projects name and context root are different if they are the same. Can't think of an alternative other than that.